# Android Webview: how to avoid SSL Certificate error when connecting to numeric IP address?

Tags: android, security, webview, ssl-certificate

My Android application uses a webview to load a html page from a public HTTPS server.
However when it is used from inside certain networks, it is not possible to use the domain address of the public server (i.e. https://myserver.com) but it is necessary to use a numeric address (not public), which redirects to the public server. This triggers an "SSL certificate error" because the certificate is bound to the domain address and not to the numeric IP address.
In the SSL error handler I can give the user the chance to proceed, however this is considered *not secure* by many security tools, even if proceeding is demanded on the user choice.

Is there a way to avoid the SSL certificate error in such conditions? Like, for instance, add a list of "trusted" numeric IP addresses? I've been told that embedding the certificate in the app can be a solution, but I think would mean to resubmit the app to the store everytime the certificate is reissued, and I would like to avoid this.

Thanks in advance for any hint you might provide.

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar Problem and with Retrofit I solved this with the following just replace `CommonConstantsRest.REST_URL` with yours:

```
protected static Retrofit getInstanceWithoutToken() {
    ConnectionSpec spec = new
            ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
            .cipherSuites(
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
            .build();
    final OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    httpClient.connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));
    httpClient
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            final Request original = chain.request();
            final Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .method(original.method(), original.body())
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(CommonConstantsRest.REST_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @tobias-lukoscheck! How should I use your code, i.e.: how this integrates with the loading of the webview at the specified URL?

Comment: @MarcelloCarrozzino could you share your code of with the webview?

Comment: You could also load the content (GET request) of your page and set it in the webview. I guess the method is loadData.

Comment: this is the "skeleton" code:
`webView = pview;`
`WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();`
`webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
`webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);`
`        [...]`
`webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {    [...]  });`
`  [...]                `
`webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {       [...]     });`

`webView.loadUrl(htmlPath);`

`